# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 + Windows 8 in SSD+Normal drives

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm gonna setup my computer with a new HD config.

I have a 320gb old SATA2 drive with Ubuntu 12.10 + Windows 7.

I'm buying a new 120gb SSD drive today, and my plan is as follows:

SSD
- 20gb partition for Ubuntu 12.10 / partition
- Rest for Windows 8

Old SATA2
- 120gb for /home Ubuntu 12.10 partition.
- Rest for Windows 8

My questions are:
- I have 4GB RAM. Should I create a swap partition? If I need to, wher should be the best place, SSD or mechanical drive?
- I guess I should install Windows 8 first to avoid W8 stepping onto Grub?
- Is it easy to setup Ubuntu to use / in one disk and /home in another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question whether to create a swap partition is directly dependent on how you use your system.  If you like to have a lot of programs open at the same time, you definitely need a swap partition.  If you're just browsing, then you might not need a swap partition.

It's very easy to setup Ubuntu to use / on one drive and /home on another.  You'll have to option to choose these locations during setup.

Before you jump into picking your SSD for specific partitions, have a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112605).  Poster number 5 explains the pros and cons very well.